# Read and list unique words from a txt file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

so my task is to:

```
Write a program to list which letters in the file seqs.txt are not A, T, C, or G. It should only list
each letter once. Hint: Start with an empty list for unknown letters. Then use two loops to scan
letters in each sequences.
```

Currently, I'm stuck at knowing how to implement two loops to scan the letters.

```
def main():
    with open('seqs.txt','r') as seqs_file:
        unknown = ("A","T","G","C")
        #unknown_list = ("B","D","E","F","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P"
                         # ,"Q","R","S","U","V","X","Y","Z")
        for unknown in seqs_file:
            if True:
                return()
            else:
                print(#the other letters not ATCG#)
main()
```

This is the code I have know. I have tried using the `.read()` command, but after that I'm not sure how to make the two loops. Would appreciate any help on getting me on the right track!

EDIT: The text file contains this:

> ATTCCATCGTATCCACACCGAGAACAACCCCATGTTGGCCTGGCAGCCAGAGGTTCTCCCTTTGGCGGTCACCTGCAGCCCGGCTGGCTTGCCAGCCCGACTGTGGGGGCCGGGTTCACACCTGGCCGGCTGTTTCTCCCATTCAAACCAATATCTGAAGGCAATTGCTTGCTCACACGAGCGGCGACTAACAAAGACAACTCTCAACAACGGATATCTTGGCTCCCGCAACGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAAATGCGATACGTAGTGTGAATTGCAGAATTCCGTGAACCATCCAATCTTTGAACGCATATTGCGCCCCACGGCCTCGGCCCAGGGCATGTCTGCCTCAGCGTCTGTTTACCCCCTCTCCCCCCTTTCACATACTGTGAAATCGGGAAGGTTGTGGTCTTGTGCTGCGGCACTTGGCCGAAATTCAGTGATACTGCAGGGACCGTTAATCGGACTCCAGCTTGGTAGGCGTTTCCCTTGTGGAATTATGCATGCCGCTGTTGGCCGTGGACCACTGCAGCTGTCAAGCAGGGAAAACCTTTCAAATT

Just as an example.

Comment: What you want to get? I'm not really understand that you expect?

Comment: Can we know content of `seqs.txt` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way for your question as per my knowledge is to read file, split it and make a list of it. To get unique elements convert it to set and simple for loop will provide you your solution.

```
f = open("seq.txt", 'r')
unknown_letters = list(f.read())
known_letters = ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']
unknown_unique_letters_set = set(unknown_letters)

for i in unknown_unique_letters_set:
    if i in known_letters:
        pass
    else:
        print(i)
```

if you don't want to use set() and want to stick to list below is the code:

```
f = open("seq.txt", 'r')
unknown_letters = list(f.read())
known_letters = ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']
visited_letters = []
for i in unknown_letters:
    if i in known_letters:
        pass
    elif i in visited_letters:
        pass
    else:
        visited_letters.append(i)

print(visited_letters)
```

Comment: Hello so from what I understand from your code provided, it prints out the known letters instead of the 'unknown'. Have tested it too and the result is wrong.

Comment: Your input file you posted now in your question don't have spaces. Try my edited solution above. Instead of spiting i have converted it to list.

Comment: Also your input file don't have any unknown letters. Try adding some of the unknown letters like MMMMMM before testing it. It will give result like single M

Comment: Does it give you answer you are looking for?

Comment: Yes! I believe I have gotten the right output. I was wondering if you could explain a little more on why is it you chose to use the set(). Would list() not work in this case?

Comment: See, in python set() only gives you unique elements. It does not allows duplicate elements. In your case you wanted unique elements so i used set(). It is also possible with list[]. It will be bit lengthy for your problem. If you wan't i can give you solution with list as well.

Comment: See the updated response above with list as well. If my response helped you don't forgot to uplike it so it will help to other people as well.

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to use sets than lists if you want uniqueness...

```
known = {"A", "T", "G", "C"}
unknown = set()
with open('seqs.txt','r') as seqs_file:
    for letter in seqs_file.read():
        unknown.add(letter)
unknown -= known
for letter in unknown:
    print(letter)
```

Comment: Have you ever thought about the punctuation and numbers that may be present in the file?

Comment: Yes, every night for at least forty minutes before sleep mercifully claims me.

Comment: so . i'm currently getting this error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'add', have tried changing it to .append but it's still saying it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah yes, you want `set()` to declare an empty set.

Comment: would you mind explaining your comment above a little more? Im just terribly new to this. Thanks!

Comment: @aislinx - You might have declaed an empy set using unknown = {}, rather you should use unknown = set()

Answer (score 1):

I'd use this and ignore stupid hints that will throw you totally off course:

```
import string

with open('seqs.txt') as fin :
    characters = [i.upper() for i in fin.read() if i in string.letters]

result = set(characters) - set(['A', 'T', 'C', 'G'])

print sorted(result)
```

Comment: hello, so IDLE is currently giving me an error saying that 'sorted' is an invalid syntax

Comment: and anothererror saying that the module 'string' has no attribute 'letters'

Comment: @aislinx for python3 please use `string.ascii_letters'

Comment: @aislinx and use `print( sorted(result) )` with additional parentheses

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    #y.txt contains this space separated string 'A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V X Y Z'
    with open('some_file.txt','r') as seqs_file:
        data = seqs_file.read().split()
        other = []
        unknown = ("A","T","G","C")
        for d in data:
            if d in unknown:
                pass
            elif d not in other:
                print(d)
                other.append(d)
main()
```